# HAProxy ACL that checks each value in header against a whitelist and denies request if at least one value is not whitelisted

Tags: acl, haproxy

I need to set up an ACL rule for my HAProxy that checks **each value** in a given header against a whitelist and denies the request if at least one value is not whitelisted.

I’ve created a small `whitelist.lst`:

```
myval1
myval2
```

And here's is my `haproxy.cfg`:

```
defaults
    mode http

frontend http_frontend
    bind *:80
    acl valid-hdr req.hdr(x-my-header) -m str -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.lst
    use_backend mysite if valid-hdr

backend mysite
    server mysite 172.10.1.1:80 check
```

Headers may contain multiple comma separated values, so I want `req.hdr` to check **each of them** against a whitelist. If at least one value is not whitelisted - request should be blocked.

Example of what I want:

```
"X-My-Header: myval1"              - valid
"X-My-Header: myval2"              - valid
"X-My-Header: myval1,myval2"       - valid
"X-My-Header: myval2,myval1"       - valid
"X-My-Header: myval1,evil,myval2"  - NOT valid
"X-My-Header: evil"                - NOT valid
```

Example of what I get now:

```
"X-My-Header: myval1"              - valid
"X-My-Header: myval2"              - valid
"X-My-Header: myval1,myval2"       - valid
"X-My-Header: myval2,myval1"       - valid
"X-My-Header: myval1,evil,myval2"  - valid
"X-My-Header: evil"                - NOT valid
```

So the current config works just in the opposite way: if at least one of the values is whitelisted - request is considered to be valid.